# do you have to run npm run production when installing a new package?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I'm quite new, I need help.

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

I have a laravel 8 project in production. I have installed this package and in local it works fine, but when I upload it to production it doesn't work. This package requires the installation of a plugin in the tailwind.config.js file.

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],
    
    theme: {
        extend: {
        },
    },

    variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'), ],
};
```

I have to run npm run production in production?
Thank you very much

Comment: `npm` installs packages into the `node_modules` directory which is not typically uploaded to a production environment as part of the deployment process. So if you've installed a package locally and then deployed your new code that relies on that package, you will need to ensure it is installed and built in production. Most hosting environments will provide a way to automate this, usually in a deployment script.

Comment: Yes, I installed the package locally, tested it, everything worked fine and uploaded it to production. I'm with laravel forge. But in production it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you will likey need run `npm install && npm run prod` in your production environment to install and build any new packages you've added locally via `npm`. In forge you can add such statements to the `Deploy Script` for your site.

Answer (score 0):

does your webpack file create a .js file in the public directory? This is the file you need to upload after you run the `npm run production`

sometimes it helps to press ctrl when reloading as the browser may cache the old js files.